# initramfs unable to find medium

Tags: linux-mint

I am trying to install Linux mint 17.3 x64 Cinnamon on my desktop, but I keep getting:

```
ACPI PCC Probe failed

initramfs unable to find a medium containing a live file system
```

However this exact USB drive worked perfectly on my laptop. The major difference between my laptop and desktop is that the desktop has an SSD (configured to run in AHCI mode) and the laptop does not have an SSD.

Is there a way to get mint working with the hard drive configured in AHCI mode?

**Things I tried**

- removing "splash" and "quiet" from the boot command (on boot hit tab)and change line to: `/casper/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/linuxmint.seed boot=casper initrd=casper/initrd.lz --`
  which gave me a few more descriptive errors.... something about windows being read-only and I needed to shut it down properly
- Overclock settings -> IOMMU mode -> Enabled. (Becuase I have a ) Error on boot: `usb 9-2: device descriptor read/64, error -32`
- UEFI boot does not work (switches straight to next boot option)

Comment: AHCI should be actually better.  There should be no issues whatsoever with AHCI in recent kernels.  Can you get into the initramfs shell (probably `break=premount` kernel parameter is what you are after, so initramfs gives you a shell before attempting to mount things)

Comment: Do you mean hit Tab at the welcome screen and append `break=premount` to `/casper/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/linuxmint.seed boot=casper initrd=casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --`

Comment: Eyyuup (although I was sure it was `e` and not `<Tab>` to edit the entry, yet I do not run Mint, they may have made some tweaks)

Comment: I tried that and still wound up at the same screen with no cmd prompt

Comment: Any other ideas? Im not sure what to even google here

Comment: Well, you need to get into a shell that is running over something on that machine.  Blind guessing will not help much.  I just do not believe that AHCI could be an issue, you may be hitting hundreds of things but some stuff I'd check are: secure boot, other USB ports, and the SATA cables.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my specific problem was shown in the error log after I removed "splash" and "quiet" from the boot prompt (select start Mint in normal mode and press Tab).

Windows was in a hibernation state and therefore couldnt be mounted by Mint.... After removing the hard drive the system booted properly into Mint.